# ghci vs prelude Haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I have recently started learning Haskell and had some questions about ghci> prompt vs prelude> prompt?

When typing ghci i get this:

```
ghci
GHCi, version 9.2.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci>
```

when checking documentation I see things like this:

```
 $ ghci
    GHCi, version 6.12.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
    Loading package base ... linking ... done.
    Prelude>
```

also in addition to this I do not get into a module once I've loaded it

```
ghci> :load main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci>
```

should look something like this?

```
ghci> :load main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main>
```

I have tried looking online, tried compiling the program

Comment: Since GHCi 9+, it no longer shows the modules loaded.

Answer (score 3):

GHCi is less verbose since version 9.0. This is because after a while the list of modules became very long, making the shell less effective.

Therefore since version 9.0, it keeps showing the `ghci>` prompt by default. You can [set the prompt with `%s>` <sup>[ghc-doc]</sup>](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.1-alpha1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:set%20prompt) to show the loaded modules instead:

```
ghci> :set prompt "%s> "
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List>
```

Answer (score 2):

This was changed in GHC 9.0.1. Earlier versions showed the modules that were loaded, but now it just shows `ghci>`.

See [the release notes for GHC 9.0.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/9.0.1-notes.html#ghci):

> #### 2.1.2.3. GHCi
>
> - GHCi prompt no longer lists loaded modules. The previous behavior can be restored with `:set prompt "%s> "` and `:set prompt-cont "%s| "`.